# Mobile Device Networking Intermitten

Tags: ios, iis, mobile, web

This is a mobile application developed using Titanium SDK 2.1.3.GA on IOS 5.

For a while now I've been battling what I though were bugs in my application and they may still be, but I can't seem to get beyond this issue.  I don't even know if this is a Titanium Mobile problem, but I'm out of ideas.

I have a web service I wrote (WCF Service) and a Titanium Mobile app that I connect with.  On my emulator it works well from a MAC that is hardwired.  I do all my testing and deploy the app to my iPhone 4gs running IOS 5.1.1 (9B206).  Now I'm running it on my iPhone with both 3g and WiFi enabled.  I send the request for data and it may or may not come back.  More often than it works, it times out.  The requests seems somewhat sluggish when they do work.  This is on our internal network through our WiFi connection.  I then turn off the WiFi on the phone and it starts to work seemingly 100%.  On top of that, it is fast.  Initially this problem was cropping up on an iPad 2 with WiFi only, which made me switch to the phone.  Both the iPad and the iPhone are running the same version OS IOS 5.1.1 (9B206).  I then deployed my app on an iPhone 5 running IOS 6 (forget the full version) with the same tests.  On WiFi it seems problematic, but on 4G LTE it seems great.

Now, I'm looking to my web server logs running IIS 6.  In a situation where my connection appears to timeout, it shows a 200 0 64 in the log.  According to another stackoverflow post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372149/iis-file-download-hangs-timeouts-sc-win32-status-64), this means that the network name is no longer available.  So it appears that the network request timed out.  All my requests are set to 30000ms timeout.  I then got the ip address of the phone from the IIS logs and decided to run tracert and it reports a single hop to the device(WiFi) from the server.  I start up ping -t on the server to the device IP and this is when it gets interesting to me.  Initially, it reports request timed out.  On the device I make a network call and during my network call I get 2 replies, 1 timed out and then 2 more replies in the course of the network communication between the server and the phone device.  Then it returns to request timed out.  I feel like the network connection is being closed by the device when it should remain open to receive the request.

Anything have any thoughts on how to go about further troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Got another WiFi router to test with and it looks like it is already running a lot better.  For this situation, I'm going to blame network infrastructure or failing device as the problem.  So the solution is the obvious eliminate this network device as the possible source of the problem and get another one to test with.  Seems to have fixed it.