# IIS 500.19 error on 0.01% of requests

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have deployed a simple [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) application delivering Podcast RSS-feeds in IIS 7. Scouring the IIS logs, we found that a tiny amount of the requests get a HTTP **500.19** error code.

Of the ~550 000 daily requests, around 600 of them fail with 500.19. Which means we successfully deliver RSS on 99.9% of the requests. I am still curious to understand why we fail for **0.1%** of them.

500.19 generally happens due to an invalid configuration. How can the config fail for only 0.1% of the requests?

I have not been able to reproduce the error manually, so **I don't have the HResult code**. This is not present in the IIS log either.

### Some details:

- Edit: **sc-win32-status is 64**
- The internal logging of the application never reports any error, suggesting the request never reaches our code.
- The error usually happens to the biggest RSS (740KB gzipped), but also happens to smaller ones (140KB gzipped).
- The failing requests usually comes from mobile clients (IOS, Android), which doesn't tell much as podcast is usually consumed on mobile.
- The application is deployed on 6 nodes, load balanced with BigIP. Config file is not shared accross nodes. The 0.1% error rate is equal on all nodes.
- We have output cache activated in IIS (but no kernel cache).

Comment: What is the HResult code for the failed requests? [This article describes HResult codes when you encounter 500.19 error...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055).

Comment: Good catch. forgot to write that I actually don't have the HResult code, as I have not been able to reproduce the error. Updated the post.

Comment: Do your IIS logs include the `Win32 Status` field? I *think* you can get it from that. P.S. This question belongs in [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) as it is not directly to do with programming.

Comment: Interesting. sc-win32-status is 64. Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372149/iis-file-download-hangs-timeouts-sc-win32-status-64), but not sure if it applies as it is for 200 OK + 64.

PS. Is it possible to move the post to ServerFault?

Comment: You can flag your question for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.

Comment: OK. Asked [the question](http://serverfault.com/questions/704848/iis-500-19-error-on-0-01-of-requests) again on Serverfault, and flagged this. Can now be deleted by a moderator.